# Expected Value for a die

Tags: probability

I have this homework problem I trying to do. I need to know where I am wrong since my answer doesn't match the book's. My answer for part a matches the book's, but not part b.

Let X be the number of 6s when a die is rolled six times, and let Y be the number of 6x when a die is rolled 12 times. Find a) E[X] and E[Y] and b)P(X > E[X]) and P(Y > E[Y])

My answer:
$$\text{a)  } X\sim Binomial(6,\frac16) \text{, } Y\sim Binomial(12,\frac16) $$
$$E[X]=6*\frac16=1 \text{, } E[Y]=12*\frac16=2$$
$$\text{b)  } Pr(X\gt E[X])=Pr(X\gt 1)=1-Pr(X\le1)$$
$$=1-(Pr(X=0)+Pr(X=1))=1-((\frac56)^6+(\frac56)^5)=.26$$

The book's answer is .66.
Could you point me to where I am mistaken?
Thanks

Comment: Book's answer would be close if it were $\Pr( X\ge E(X))$.

Comment: You are not mistaken; the book is it seems.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$You're doing just fine!

As a quick verification that the book is wrong: it couldn't possibly be the case that $P(X>1)=.66$, as otherwise
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X]&=\sum_{i=0}^{6}i\cdot P(X=i)\\
&\geq 1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X>1)\\
&\approx 0.34+2\cdot0.66\\
&=1.66,
\end{align}
$$
whereas we know $\E[X]=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is fine.  It is probably a typo in the book.

As a check, the chance of getting exactly two sixes in six throws is ${6 \choose 2}(\frac 16)^2(\frac 56)^4\approx 0.20$  The chance of getting even more should be rather small, so $0.26$ to get two or more seems very reasonable.